# what is the difference between data: and :data in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

I am working with ruby on rails, before starting rails,I learn some ruby and I know about:symbols as these are unique through out our application

but while learning rails, i encountered a wired symbols `symbol:` when working with rails models as I have created the rails model as

```
def up
    create_table :users do |t|
        t.string "email", :limit =>50, :null =>false
        t.column "password", :string, :limit =>30, :null => false
        #data types,binary, boolean, data, decima, float, integer,  text, time
        #these are the differentdata types
        #we can also have options
        #:default
        #:precision for decimal
        t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

and I was so confused between the `:null` and `null:` define in the above code, I know `:null` is symbol and what `null:` is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are the syntax for defining key-value pairs in a Hash in Ruby.

```
# Older Hash syntax; before Ruby 1.9 e.g. { :key => value }
    :limit => 50
    :null => false
```

And:

```
# Latest Hash syntax; Ruby 1.9 and higher versions e.g. { key: value }
    null: false 
    limit: 50
```

In both cases, `null` is a Symbol.

See this short article on [Ruby 1.9 and the new hash syntax](http://breakthebit.org/post/8453341914/ruby-19-and-the-new-hash-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

`symbol: true` is exactly the same as `:symbol => true`. `symbol:` is just a new syntax in ruby 1.9 and higher.

In ruby 1.8.7 and lower versions, only `:symbol => true` is supported. While in ruby 1.9+, both of these are supported.